How to Access sql_alchemy_conn After Update
In the past, we followed the instructions at https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/access-airflow-database to access the Airflow database for exporting job history data.
A recent Airflow/Cloud Composer update (to composer-2.6.6-airflow-2.7.3), though, causes the sql_alchemy_conn value to be hidden in the Airflow UI, so we can no longer find the password needed to connect to the database as documented on the above page.
How do you get to that info now?

Hey, did you find the solution?

Unfortunately, no... Last I checked, they still haven't updated the docs, either.
